# Trouble Exporting Google Sheet to Excel Using GDrive API .v3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying to use the GDrive REST API .v3 to export and save a Google Sheet to the local file system in Excel format (actually the Open Office MIME type) to no avail.

I'e also tried using the direct links:

```
string path1 = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/" + fileId + "/edit?usp=sharing"; //DOESN'T WORK; EXPECTED
string path2 = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId; //FILE NOT FOUND
string path3 = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=" + fileId; //DOWNLOADS A MESS
string path4 = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + fileId + "?alt=media"; //Google API: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
WebClient oClient = new WebClient();
oClient.DownloadFile(path4, saveAs);
result = path4;
```

AND...

```
var webcontentlink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId;
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file = 
driveService.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
var x = driveService.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(webcontentlink);
byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
File.WriteAllBytes(saveAs, arrBytes);
```

This is the code I would like to have work:

```
//GET THE MIME TYPE OF THE GOOGLE FILE
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File oFile = 
driveService.Files.Get(fileId).Execute();
string mimeType = oFile.MimeType;
bool googleDoc = true;

switch (mimeType) {
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.document": {
        mimeType = "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text";
        break;
    }
case "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet": {
        mimeType = "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet";
        break;
    }
case "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing": {
        mimeType = "image/png";
        break;
    }
case "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation": {
        mimeType = "application/pdf";
        break;
    }
default: {
        googleDoc = false;
        break;
    }
}
var oRequest = driveService.Files.Export(fileId, mimeType);
oRequest.Fields = "*";
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
oRequest.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged += (IDownloadProgress progress) => 
{
    switch (progress.Status) {
        case DownloadStatus.Downloading: {
                result = progress.BytesDownloaded.ToString();
                break;
            }
        case DownloadStatus.Completed: {
                result = "Export complete.";
                break;
            }
        case DownloadStatus.Failed: {
                result = "Export failed.";
                break;
            }
    }
};
oRequest.Download(stream);
SaveStream(stream, saveAs);

private static void SaveStream(MemoryStream stream, string saveAs) {
    //PURPOSE: SAVE THE FILE STREAM TO A FILE.
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(saveAs, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)) {
        stream.CopyTo(file);
    }
}
```

The API sample code says "Download Complete," but the file content either comes out mangled or blank. I have the right MIME type, etc. and have tried this several different ways. I want to be able to successfully export a file from GDrive, ideally at least a Google Sheet to Excel. This is a very popular question on here, but no one seems to have answered it...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the MIME types listed in the documentation ([Download Files Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)
) don't work. I did find MIME types that do work. Below are the details from testing the various possible MIME conversion types (see comments on each line):

```
switch (mimeType) {
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet": {
        mimeType = "text/csv"; //CSV: WORKING
        //mimeType = "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet"; //OPEN OFFICE: NOT WORKING (GARBLED)
        //mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; //MS EXCEL: NOT WORKING (GARBLED)
        break;
    }
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.document": {
        //mimeType = "text/plain"; //PLAIN TEXT: WORKING (DOUBLE TEXT IN THE FILE, BUT NOT THE API EXPLORER)
        mimeType = "application/rtf"; //RICH TEXT: WORKING
        //mimeType = "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text"; //OPEN OFFICE DOC: NOT WORKING (GARBLED)
        //mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; //MS WORD DOCUMENT (GARBLED)
        break;
    }
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.presentation": {
        mimeType = "application/pdf"; //PLAIN TEXT: WORKING
        //mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-    officedocument.presentationml.presentation"; //MS POWER POINT (GARBLED)
        //mimeType = "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation"; //OPEN OFFICE (GARBLED)
        break;
    }
    case "application/vnd.google-apps.drawing": {
        mimeType = "image/png"; //PNG: WORKING
        //mimeType = "image/jpeg"; //JPEG: WORKING
        //mimeType = "image/pdf"; //NOT WORKING (INVALID FILE: ACROBAT DOESN'T LIKE IT)
        break;
    }
    default: {
        googleDoc = false;
        break;
    }
}
```